# LINQ join on non equal keys

Tags: c#, sql, .net, linq

I need to convert this SQL query into LINQ

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 t1 
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.LogDate >= t2.StartDate AND t1.LogDate <= t2.EndDate
```

What should be the LINQ for above SQL query?

Comment: I don't see a problem here!! No attempt to solve this?

Comment: Did you try looking for basic Linq examples? For example:
https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-Restriction-Operators-b15d29ca

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LINQ only supports join on equal keys, I suggest using cross join. Depending on your query optimizer it may be converted to inner join

```
from t1 in Table1
from t2 in Table2
where t1.LogDate >= t2.StartDate && t1.LogDate <= t2.EndDate
select new { t1, t2 }
```

Comment: @VDohnal - It will most likely be converted into an `inner join`

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully if you are joining these tables you thought ahead and designed you Database with a foreign key reference in Table2 to Table1. Assuming you did that, the Lambda expression would be as follows:

Table1     Table2

PK-> ID    FK-> T1_ID

```
db.Table1.Join(db.Table2.ToList(),
               t1 => t1.ID,
               t2 => t2.T1_ID,
               (t1, t2) => new { Table1, Table2})
         .Where(result => result.Table1.LogDate >= result.Table2.StartDate &&
                          result.Table1.LogDate <= result.Table2.EndDate);
```